# Tell Pyright to ignore Decimal to float conversion

Tags: python-3.x, pyright

In this contrived example, I want pyright to accept that using a Decimal instead of a float is fine (I am aware of the limitations, but this is what is needed and I am fine with the consequences).

```py
from decimal import Decimal
d = Decimal(1.0)
f: float = d
```

Pyright will say on the line `f: float = d`:

> Expression of type "Decimal" cannot be assigned to declared type "float"

> "Decimal" is incompatible with "float" Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)

The options I know of are:

- ignore `reportGeneralTypeIssues` completely (that would remove a lot of the power of Pyright, even inside one file)
- ignore `reportGeneralTypeIssues` on each line where I have the Decimal/float conversion (visually very very polluting in my codebase)

Is there a way to tell "Ignore `reportGeneralTypeIssues` errors related to Decimal -> float conversions"?

**Edit**:

I know that there will be conversion happening down the line in my code (I am basically working with 2 types of pydantic models: one with Decimal, one with float), so I am basically looking for a no boilerplate option (yes, I could convert all Decimals to float manually, but that's not what I am looking for).

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to this, so I'll list a couple below:

### 1. Convert the type

This is the most straight-forward, we simply convert the object to a float prior to use. I would recommend this because then the types actually reflect the objects used. The entire point of using types is so that objects you use have the properties you expect.

```py
from decimal import Decimal
d = float(Decimal(1.0))
f: float = d
```

### 2. Masking the type

This way is not ideal, but you can (for no runtime cost) mask what type is really being used behind a "cast".

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import cast
d = cast(float, Decimal(1.0))
f: float = d
```

This just overrides the type of the item effectively.

### Syntax

You could wrap either of these in a function for brevity e.g.:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import cast

def MyDecimal(num: float) -> float:
    return cast(float, Decimal(num))

f: float = MyDecimal(1.0)
```

With the above syntax you can also make use almost exactly the same, with a change to the import line:

`new_decimal.py`

```py
from decimal import Decimal as DecOld
from typing import cast

def Decimal(num: float) -> float:
    return cast(float, DecOld(num))
```

`used_file.py`

```py
from .new_decimal import Decimal
d = Decimal(1.0)
f: float = d
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mark, this is A fair point indeed. I am really looking into pyright configuration because I know that all `Decimal` will be converted to `float` automagically at some point down the line, and I do not want to add boilerplate. I should have added that to the question. otherwise, I do wholeheartedly agree with your answer.

Comment: Hi Guillaume - ah that makes sense. Personally, I would then probably just use the cast solution, as with a bit of fine tuning this can look almost exactly the same as what you had. Just name "MyDecimal" -> "Decimal" - then the only difference would be in the import line.

Comment: I've now modified the example to include this - hope it's useful!

Comment: I had not thought of that, indeed, that would work. Thanks!